# plot mean and confidence interval - matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I want to make a plot that splits a dataset and shows the amount of observations per category on the left axis and a confidence interval (e.g. 90%) including the mean for a certain observed value on the right axis.

It should look like this:

[image]

I know  how to use `ax.hist()` or `ax.bar()` for the first job. A second axis is easily made using `ax.twinx()`. However, after trying both `ax.boxplot()` and `ax.violinplot()`, I believe neither could do the job (plotting the confidence interval + mean) correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a look at `plt.errorbar`. You need to compute the mean and CI accordingly.

Comment: [`ax.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html) takes also the argument `yerr` for the y-axis error bar.